# jquery - speedometer arrow imitation, rotating arrow towards mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to implement a feature as this: 
[image]

where the arrow is going around based on the location of the mouse:
[image]

Current code turns around the arrow from the center. Problem: the arrow should be going around only from the left end:

```
          var box=$(".box");
var boxCenter=[box.offset().left+box.width()/2, box.offset().top+box.height()/2];

$(document).mousemove(function(e){    


    var angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX- boxCenter[0],- (e.pageY- boxCenter[1]) )*(180/Math.PI);     

    box.css({ "-webkit-transform": 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});    
    box.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    box.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});

});


.box{
 background-image:url("Wheelizate Tabs - Apart left_files/tick.png");

    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;

    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}

  <div class="box" style="z-index:10000;margin-left: 70px;margin-top: 200px;"></div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/tuz4y6r4/](https://jsfiddle.net/tuz4y6r4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `transform-origin : center left;` for the `box` to rotate from the left. By default the `transform-origin` is `center center`. Checkout the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/63qxdg3b/

Comment: there is a distance between the black box and the mouse, i need the box to be exactly near the mouse so that user can navigate through it.

Comment: the arrow, black box should be pointing towards the mouse, so lets say I am pointing towards Policy advocacy and the arrow(black box) should point there too